# Error after adding @import "bootstrap"; ArgumentError in Static_pages#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm at 5.1.2 of the railstutorial, I have just installed Bootstrap-sass (I've double checked, the gem is there). http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top

I added this file:
app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

And when I give it this content:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

My http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home does not work anymore. It gives the following error:

```
ArgumentError in Static_pages#home

Showing c:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

different prefix: "e:/" and "c:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets"
  (in c:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <html>
3:   <head>
4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
Rails.root: c:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___557356520_29974776'
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you have your ruby installer and your project on a different path?

Comment: Yes, Rails installer is here: E:\RailsInstaller . The project is here C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app . Is this a problem? So far everything has been working fine

Comment: Ok ive copied my project to the E drive and this solved the problem, thanks. I hope though that I wont cause problems with Github and heroku

Answer (score 4):

Your gems is in `E:` while your app is in `C:\`

When trying to @import, Assets module will search several places including gem path. But it can't recognize the disk within the path. That's why your @import fails.

Suggestion: Put your app and gems in same disk.

Side note: Don't use Windows for Rails development at all.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you mind sharing why Windows is bad for Rails development? (sorry Im a bit of a noob)